# Where is .NET Framework 4.7.1?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have Visual Studio 2017. In a project's Properties page, I can select for Target framework 4.7.2, 4.6.2, 4.6.1, 4.6, and other lower versions. I don't see a choice of 4.7.1.

According to https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks, 4.7.1 is "included in Visual Studio 2017".

I have to deploy a console app to a target machine that has up to 4.7.1. Does it mean I should install 4.7.1 on my development PC manually?

Comment: net471 targeting pack: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56119

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 4.7.1. pack is indeed included, but it is optional to install.

You can re-run the Visual Studio installer (perhaps after first [downloading the most recent one](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/)).

**Run** it, then click [**Modify**] to check if you did not install it.
If not, you can add it from there:

> [image: VS installer]